# wont display drop down

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
    <form>
<asp:Repeater id="rptComments" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
            <tr>   
                <th style="width:200px;">Answers</th> 
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:200px;"><asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownForChecklistAnswers" runat="server" /></th>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        <asp:Button id="button" text="Submit" OnClick="Page_Load" runat="server" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
 List<Checklist_Record_Choice> CLRC =
            (from choice in db.Checklist_Record_Choices
             select choice).ToList();

        dropDownForChecklistAnswers.DataSource = CLRC;

        DropDownList1.DataTextField = Text;//Text being the name of column2 in the table (which contains yes, no, n/a)

        dropDownForChecklistAnswers.DataBind();
```

ERROR: dropDownForChecklistAnswers does not exist in the current context???
please advise

---

EDIT;
thanks for reply. I have

```
public void OnReptDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ClarkeDBDataContext db1 = new ClarkeDBDataContext();
    List<string> CLRC =
    (from choice in db1.Checklist_Record_Choices
     select choice.Text).ToList();

    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("dropDownForChecklistAnswers");
    ddl.DataSource = CLRC;
}
```

but DropDownList ddl is coming back as object ref not set to instance of an object...why is it null??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.findcontrol.aspx) to access a control which is part of a Repeater's template.

Subscribe to the `OnItemDataBound` of the Repeater (set the attribute `OnItemDataBound="OnReptDataBound"`)

And then in your code behind do the following

```
void OnReptDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) 
   {
     DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList )e.Item.FindControl("dropDownForChecklistAnswers");
     ddl.DataSource = ....
```

Comment: Updated answer, try checking the [ItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype.aspx)